# How to set far expires date on http response in django?

Tags: django, cache-control

How can I set now + 1year expiration for my http responses properly in django?
Can I do that using the `render()` shortcut?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using decorators, see the relevant docs on using [per-view cache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#the-per-view-cache).

Comment: It reads as though django actually keeps a copy of the generated html response so that a forced reload is not possible. Is this true? I'd prefer to just set the headers.

Comment: @jozxyqk If you prefer to just set the headers see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/58092481/4387229

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is to use `patch_response_headers(response, cache_timeout=None)` from `django.utils.cache`. This will simply set the `Expires` and `Cache-Control` HTTP headers on the `response` object according to the specified timeout in seconds.

For example in your view code you can apply it to your `HttpResponse` object before you return it:

```
from django.utils.cache import patch_response_headers

# Add Expires and Cache-Control headers to cache in browser for 5 minutes
patch_response_headers(response, cache_timeout=300)

return response
```

This may be a better solution if you only want the browser to cache the response for a specific amount of time with no caching occurring on the server.

See the Django documentation for more details:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.cache.patch_response_headers